# Android RecyclerView Multiple ItemType Insertion Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using the 22.2.1 RecyclerView library.

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that displays a vertical list of items that are backed by an `ArrayList`.

In certain situations (let's say if `X == true`) it will also display a different item at position 0. `getItemCount` looks like this:

```
return (X ? 0 : 1) + items.size();
```

When X becomes true I call `notifyItemInserted(0)`. After that, `onBindViewHolder` gets called with a position equal to `getItemCount`, followed by `onBindViewHolder` getting called with a position of 0.

The problem is that position 1 and 2 (which is position 0 and 1 in `items`) are both displaying the item for `items.get(1)`. To illustrate here is what is displayed in both scenarios:

**`X == false`**

1. Item 1
2. Item 2
3. Item 3

**`X == true`**

1. X
2. Item 2
3. Item 2
4. Item 3

However, if `X == true` initially then everything is displayed correctly.

My workaround is:

```
notifyItemInserted(0);
notifyItemRangeChanged(1, items.size()); // workaround
```

But I don't believe I should have to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you getting the value of x as a part of your data?

Comment: @Kaveesh can you elaborate?

Comment: I am saying that the dataset/response that you are getting in which you have all the item values, is the value of x a part of that dataset/response that you are getting?

Comment: No, it comes from a separate source, although I don't see how that would have any effect.